# Magento 2 use custom block in extended template

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to use a block in order to get some data in a template, but it's not working.

Here is my block

```
class Question extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
{

    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function test()
    {
        return "OK";
        //return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }

}
```

And this is my   `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="question.tab" as="question" template="Semaine2_TP::product/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Questions</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block name="question" class="Semaine2\TP\Block\Question"  cacheable="false" template="Semaine2_TP::question/info.phtml" group="detailed_info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But with this, only the delivery_info.phtml is printed, and the info.phtml seems to be ignored.

Actually what I would like to be able to do is to use my test function from the block inside my delivery_info.phtml in order to get an action target URL for example or to get the customer if he is logged in.

But when I call $block in my phtml he always seems to search into the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` which is normal I guess.

New to magento 2 and no idea how to deal with this. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to use Magento View Models instead of Block classes to separate business logic
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

`catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block name="question.tab" as="question" template="Semaine2_TP::product/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Questions</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block name="question" cacheable="false" template="Semaine2_TP::question/info.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Semaine2\TP\ViewModel\Question</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

`app/code/Semaine2/TP/ViewModel/Question.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Semaine2\TP\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

/**
 * Class Question.
 */
class Question implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Get current product.
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct(): Product
    {
        if ($this->product === null) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        }

        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `$block->getChildHtml()` in your delivery_info.phtml file?
Since you have a custom block and template, I think you need to explicitly call a toHtml for your block. You can also pass in your custom block name to the function, if not I believe all child block HTMLs will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I was extending the wrong Block.

The block need to extends `use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;`

Sadly this magento native block is using deprecated arguments, but I think we can't escape from this if we want to be able to call the construct.